# Is there a significance to the number of witnesses at Har Sinai?

Tags: edim-witnesses, har-sinai, gematria-numerology

It is said there were 2-3 million present at Matan Torah. (Not sure what the consensus on the exact number is.)

Numbers are important in Judaism. 613 mitzvot. Seven days of creation, gematria, thirteen attributes of mercy, twenty-four kohanic gifts, etc. Just wondering if there was a significance to the total people present. Could there have been just maybe 10,000 present? Ten million? Why the 2-3 million?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is? What type of significance are you looking for regarding the number of witnesses?

Comment: Numbers are important in Judaism. 613 mitzvot. Seven days of creation, etc. Just wondering if there was a significance to the total that were present. Could there have been just maybe 10,000 present? Ten million? Why the 2-3 million?

Comment: Wasn't there exactly 600000 Jewish souls at Har Sinai?

Comment: I learned that number was only for the men. That didn't include the women, children and proselytizes which brought the total to two or three million.

Comment: Numbers are very important to Judaism, specifically 7. Days of creation, the Shabbat, etc. etc. the Bible always exaggerates. There were not millions of people at Sinai. Probably a few hundred thousand.

Comment: @Jonathan The Bible never says there were millions of people at Sinai. It says approximately 600,000 men between the ages of 20 and 60 left Egypt. Beyond that is speculation on the part of the Rishonim, who come up with the 3-4 million number often cited.

Comment: @Ephraim77 -- Why does there have to be a "significance" to numbers? So there are "613 mitzvot, 7 days of creation, and 13 attributes".  What is the significance of these numbers?  If there had been 713 mitzvot, 8 days of creation, and 19 attributes, so what?

Comment: There are many significance and symbolic meanings about the numbers in Judaism. For example, the seven weekdays (seventh day falls on Shabbat) recalls the seven days of creation and that there is a G-d.

Comment: I will try to write more fully trm.

Comment: Since the Torah does not speak of the number of women and children, then the number of them would be a matter of speculation only and not a matter of significence.